# How to get the min elements inside an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

This is what I tried:

```
Math.min([1,2,3])
```

But only get `NaN`...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use `apply`:

```
Math.min.apply(null,[1,2,3]); //=> 1
```

[From devguru](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/apply.html):

> `Function.apply(thisArg[, argArray])`
> the apply method allows you to call a
> function and specify what the keyword
> this will refer to within the context
> of that function. The thisArg argument
> should be an object. Within the
> context of the function being called,
> this will refer to thisArg. The second
> argument to the apply method is an
> array. The elements of this array will
> be passed as the arguments to the
> function being called. The argArray
> parameter can be either an array
> literal or the deprecated arguments
> property of a function.

In this case the first argument is of no importance (hence: null), the second is, because the array is passed as arguments to `Math.min`. So that's the 'trick' used here.

[**edit nov. 2020**] This answer is rather old. Nowadays (with Es20xx) you can use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to spread an array to arguments for `Math.min`.

```
Math.min(...[1,2,3]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use JS spread operator to avoid extra coding:

```
console.log(Math.min(...[1,2,3]))
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to iterate through the array. AFAIK there is no `array_min` in JS.

```
var i, min = arr[0];
for (i=1; i<arr.length; i++)
    min = Math.min(min, arr[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Math.min(1, 2, 3)
1
```

Since, `[1,2,3]` cannot be converted to a number, it returns `NaN`.

More: [Mozilla Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min)

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
Array.min = function( array ){
        return Math.min.apply( Math, array );
    };
```

Check this link out - http://ejohn.org/blog/fast-javascript-maxmin/

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass it an array (which is what is not a number or `NaN` in this case), just pass it the numbers as arguments to the function.  Like this:

```
Math.min(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: @compile then use something like vbence suggests.

Comment: @compile-fan: Why do you have to?  The function is expecting numbers as arguments, not an array.  If you have to pass an array to a function then I suppose you could write a wrapper for `Math.min()` which takes an array and breaks it up before calling `Math.min()` with the array's elements.  (And even checks the input to make sure they're all numbers.)