# Algorithm of the greatest intersect of word in set of words

Tags: javascript, algorithm

**The story behind**

I am creating a voice controlled application using `x-webkit-speech` which is surprisingly good (the feature, not my app), but sometimes the user (me) mumbles a bit. It would be nice to accept the command if some reasonable part of the word matches some reasonable part of some reasonable command. So I search for the holy grail called *Algorithm of the Greatest Intersect of Word in Set of Words*. Could some fresh bright mind drive me out of the cave of despair?

**Example**

```
"rotation" in ["notable","tattoo","onclick","statistically"]
```

should match *tattoo* because it has the longest intersect with *rotation* (**tat_o**). *statistically* is the second best (**tati** intersect), because longer part of the word needs to be ignored (but this is bonus condition, it would be acceptable without it).

**Notes**

- I use Czech language where the pronunciation is very close to its written form
- javascript is the preffered language, but any pseudocode is acceptable
- the minimal length of the intersect should be a parameter of the algorithm

**What have I tried?**

Well, it is pretty embarassing....

```
for(var i=10; i>=4; --i) // reasonable substring
for(var word in words) // for all words in the set
for(var j=0; j<word.length-i; ++j) // search for any i substring
// aaargh... three levels of abstraction is too much for me
```

Comment: Is this the same as the [edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) but with deletions weighted at 0?

Comment: If by distance you mean the number of different letters in chunk, then yes.

Comment: @JanTuron, by "edit distance", I mean the widely-used algorithm with that name.

Comment: Just wikipedied it... I guess the edit distance could be helpful, but I still have a headache.

Comment: The Levenshtein distance algorithm is what you're looking for. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) it is in Wikipedia with a couple of sample versions in C.

Comment: also see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_string_searching  To be clear, are you concerned with the speed of your algorithm or the accuracy?

Comment: @AndrewW the brute force (O(n^3)) would be enough, I have less than 100 commands. However, I still have troubles putting it together. Maybe I'm just tired right now, I guess I can use Jason's link later.

Comment: @JanTuroň, I just want you to know, you've obliterated productivity for me for like the next week. I just did a tuple match scoring algorithm, combined it with Levenshtein distance, and am now modifying to account for phonetic similarities. I have absolutely no use for this code, but I'm having way too much fun with it. :)

Comment: @JasonNichols I've just made voice controlled program menu: in lucky Czech there's no difference between phonetic and literal similarities, so it would be handy to have english version of the algorithm. So thanks for your passionate effort, I hope you'll eventually use it, too.

Comment: Google cloud api provides alternative matches with probabilities on streaming audio, see here  https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/word-confidence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an algorithm that seems to work. I have no idea how good it performs compared to other already established algorithms (I suspect it perform worse) but maybe it gives you an idea how you could do it:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bTPZx/1/)**

```
var minInt = 3;
var arr = ["notable","tattoo","onclick","statistically"];
var word = "rotation";

var res = [];
if (word.length >= minInt) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var comp = arr[i];
        var m = 0;
        if (comp.length >= minInt) {
            for (var l = 0; l < comp.length - minInt + word.length - minInt + 1; l++) {
                var subcomp = l > word.length - minInt ? comp.substring(l - word.length + minInt) : comp;
                var subword = l < word.length - minInt ? word.substring(word.length - minInt - l) : word;
                var minL = Math.min(subcomp.length, subword.length);
                var matches = 0;
                for (var k = 0; k < minL; k++) {
                    if (subcomp[k] === subword[k]) {
                        matches++;
                    }
                }
                if (matches > m) {
                    m = matches;
                }
            }
        }
        res[i] = m >= minInt ? m : null;
    }
}

console.log(res);
```

What happens is, that it compares the two strings by "moving" on against the other and calculates the matching letters in each position. Here you see the compared "sub"words for `rotation vs. notable`:

```
ion / notable --> one match on index 1
tion / notable --> no match
ation / notable --> no match
tation / notable --> one match on index 2
otation / notable --> no match
rotation / notable --> three matches on index 1,2,3
rotation / otable --> no match
rotation / table --> no match
rotation / able --> no match
rotation / ble  --> no match
```

As you see, the maximum number of matches is 3 and that is what it would return.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation of a Levenshtein Distance Calculator in Javascript.

It returns an object containing the matching command and distance.

```
var commandArr = ["cat", "dog", "fish", "copy", "delete"]
var testCommand = "bopy";

function closestMatch(str, arr)
{
    //console.log("match called");
    var matchDist = [];
    var min, pos;
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    {
        matchDist[i]=calcLevDist(str, arr[i]);
        console.log("Testing "+ str + " against " + arr[i]);
    }
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442109/how-to-get-the-min-elements-inside-an-array-in-javascript
    min = Math.min.apply(null,matchDist);
    pos = matchDist.indexOf(min);

    var output = { match : arr[pos],
                  distance : matchDist[pos]
                 };

    return output;
}

function calcLevDist (str1, str2)
{
    //console.log("calc running");

    var cost = 0 , len1, len2;
    var x = 1;
    while(x > 0)
    {
        len1 = str1.length;
        console.log("Length of String 1 = " + len1);
        len2 = str2.length;
        console.log("Length of String 2 = " + len2);

        if(len1 == 0)
        {
            cost+= len2;
            return cost;
        }
        if(len2 == 0)
        {    
            cost+= len1;
            return cost;
        }
        x = Math.min(len1,len2);

        if(str1.charAt(len1 -1) != str2.charAt(len2 -1))
        {
            cost++;
        }
        else
            console.log(str1.charAt(len1-1) + " matches " + str2.charAt(len2-1));

        str1 = str1.substring(0, len1 -1 );
        str2 = str2.substring(0, len2 -1 );


        console.log("Current Cost = " + cost);
   }


}

var matchObj = closestMatch(testCommand, commandArr);
var match = matchObj["match"];
var dist = matchObj["distance"];

$("#result").html("Closest match to " + testCommand + " = " + match + " with a Lev Distance of " + dist + "." )
```

You can mess around with the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ckkkK/).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you basilikum and JasonNichols and also Mike and Andrew for the comments, it really helped me to finish the algorithm. I come up with my own brute force `O(n^3)` solution in case someone runs into this question with the same problem.

Anyone is invited to play with [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L2TLV/) to improve it.

**The algorithm**

```
/**
 * Fuzzy match for word in array of strings with given accurancy
 * @param string needle word to search
 * @param int accurancy minimum matching characters
 * @param array haystack array of strings to examine
 * @return string matching word or undefined if none is found
 */
function fuzzyMatch(needle,accurancy,haystack) {
  function strcmpshift(a,b,shift) {
    var match=0, len=Math.min(a.length,b.length);
    for(var i in a) if(a[i]==b[+i+shift]) ++match;
    return match;
  }
  function strcmp(a,b) {
    for(var i=0,max=0,now; i<b.length; ++i) {
      now = strcmpshift(a,b,i);
      if(now>max) max = now;
    }
    return max;
  }

  var word,best=accurancy-1,step,item;
  for(var i in haystack) {
    item = haystack[i];
    step = Math.max(strcmp(item,needle),strcmp(needle,item));
    if(step<=best) continue;
    best=step, word=item;
  };
  return word;
}
```

**Example**

```
var word = "rotation";
var commands = ["notable","tattoo","onclick","statistically"];
// find the closest command with at least 3 matching characters
var command = fuzzyMatch(word,3,commands);
alert(command); // tattoo
```